# this.method = function(){} VS obj.prototype.method = function (){}

Tags: javascript, function, object

As a c#/.net dev, I love to toy around with JavaScript in my spare time -- creating my own libraries/frameworks and such. Admittedly, they're not much (really nothing more than a loose collections of functions), but the purpose is to learn; not for other people to use.

I usually extend a basic JavaScript object this way

```
obj = function () {
    //basic object stuff
    this.method = function () {
        //other stuff
    };
    return this;
};
```

This allows me to create other objects and chain methods together, which is really slick:

```
obj('arg1').method();
```

Two Examples: [jQuery Knock-off](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/vis/jl.js), [List-Item Sorter](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/js-sort/js-sort.js)

However, I have recently seen, in much more function code than my own, objects accomplish the same functionality this way:

```
function obj(){
    //stuff
}
obj.prototype.method = function () {
    //stuff
};
```

Example: [Reddit Chrome Extension](https://github.com/Kerrick/Mostly-Harmless/blob/master/js/common.js)

Both ways seem to accomplish the same end, and I'm not partial to the look of either syntax.  Is there a particular situation where one would be more useful than the other?  What do these methods offer that makes them more desirable than the other?

**Edit**

Consider the following code:

```
var dice = function (sides) {
    this.roll(){
        return 4 //guaranteed to be random
    }
};

var d1 = dice(6);
d1.roll()  // 4;
var d2 = dice(20);
d2.roll()  // 4
```

Are d1 and d2 different objects, as they appear to me? Or are they pointers/nicknames to one object (var dice)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Comment: FYI: Your first example works because you're actually creating `method` on the global `window` object, and then returning the global. (Unless you've excluded some key code that changes its meaning). Your `dice` example won't work at all because of invalid syntax and fixing the syntax, `d1` and `d2` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
this.method = function(){};
```

Only works for that specific instance.

```
Obj.prototype.method = function(){};
```

Will work for every instance of `Obj`

Though in order to take advantage of `prototype` you should do

```
var o = new Obj(); // Note that functions intended to be used with "new" should be capitalized

o.method();
```

---

### Dice Example

I'll assume you intended to `return this` in your `dice()` function.

That example is not really common, because calling a function **does not create a new object**. In your dice case you would be assigning a method to `this`, which inside the function is `window` the global object, and then returning it.

The outcome would be the same object (`window`) in both `d1` and `d2`, with a method `roll` which would be reassigned in the 2nd call.

To achieve what you want you should create the instances with `new`, like this:

```
var d1 = new Dice(6); // remember capitalization is important here
var d2 = new Dice(20);
```

This will however create 2 `roll` functions, which is correct but wastes memory since the function can be shared by doing:

```
Dice.prototype.roll = function() { /* return random awesomeness */ };
```

Hope that clarifies things

Comment: If he gave his first function a name and used it as a constructor there would be no difference though, right?

Comment: Yes there would be. The `method` won't be shared, you would be effectively creating a new function for each new object, wasting memory. There wouldn't be a difference in behavior though

Comment: @Michael could you edit your question with this extra code? It's hard to read (and answer) it here