# Class inheritance with method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript app development.When i came with functions and all i have found a code like

```
function Parenizor(value) {
console.log(this.setValue());
}

Parenizor.method('setValue', function () {
console.log('am called');
});

Parenizor.method('getValue', function () {
return 1;
});

Parenizor.method('toString', function () {
return 2;
});
```

And when i called the function like

`var a = new Parenizor(1)`

`a.setValue()`

It throws me error like `Undefined not a function`..Why is it like this ??..Hope anyone here can find my mistake ..Thanz ..:)

Comment: How about `Parenizor.prototype.setValue = function(){code}` ?..

Comment: @Izzey yeah i know to call via prototype ..but i just wanna call it via .method() ..is it possible like i did or is there any way to call with .method()

Comment: Please do not use Crockford as a reference to classical inheritance. None of his code does it correctly and he wants private variables because he's worried about encapsulation but then brakes it by modifying objects he doesn't own (Function and Object prototype) maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code comes from [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html), by Douglas Crockford.

I guess you didn't read this part:

> To make the examples above work, I wrote four [sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) methods. First,
>   the `method` method, which adds an instance method to a class.
>
> ```
> Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
>     this.prototype[name] = func;
>     return this;
> };
> ```

Comment: ..yeah exactly i got this code from CrickFord blog ..i didnt get what you mean by sugar methods ..can you provide the working by an example

Comment: Simply copy-paste the code to the top of your javascript

Comment: Just include that code before attempting to use `Parenizor.method`.

Comment: @Oriol i have added the code above  but didnt get the result..can  you provide the  fullcode in ur answer ..it would be really helpful.

Comment: @Oriol i have aded the code you given me in the answr ..but it still throws the errir..

Comment: Breaking encapsulation by modifying objects you don't own and then calling it sugar. Maybe a warning would be appropriate here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FInheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you define a method. Do it like this:

```
function K() {}

K.prototype.setValue = function () {};

K.prototype.getValue = function () {};
```

Comment: More explanation:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918509/this-method-function-vs-obj-prototype-method-function

Comment: so calling like Parenizor.method('method') is invalid ??

Comment: @user3902466 No, it's not invalid syntax. But it doesn't exist by default, you must define `Function.prototype.method` manually.

Comment: @Oriol yeah ..i got that ..but i have to ask you one thing too ..so why that .method came into action from crockfords blog ??

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is OO, not with classes, but with prototypes.
First when you declare Parenizor, you're declaring a 'constructor'.
You probaly want this:

```
function Parenizor(){
    var value = null;

    this.setValue = function(val){
        value = val;
    };

    this.getValue = function(){
        return value;
    };

    this.toString = function(){
        return String(value);
    };
}
```

Or also, setting into the object prototype:

```
function Parenizor(){}
Parenizor.prototype._value = null;
Parenizor.prototype.setValue = function(){...};
Parenizor.prototype.getValue = function(){...};
Parenizor.prototype.toString = function(){...};
```